# Can someone explain how to upgrade Django to another long-term support (LTS) release?

Tags: django, python-3.x

So Dood has a nice Django update graph...

https://arunrocks.com/django-release-schedule-and-python-3/

[image]

And I would like to upgrade from Django 1.11.17 to 2.2.  I'm seeing recommendations from the Django project to incrementally upgrade.  But how is a pip install --upgrade django going to change the current Django project from python 2.7 to python 3.6?  Preciate it!

Comment: It isn't. You will have to create a new virtualenv and clone your project into it.

Comment: The python version you're using is independent of the Django version (except you MUST upgrade to > 3.4 to use Django 2.2). If you're still on python 2.7, I'd recommend you first upgrade your virtualenv to python 3.6: create a new virtualenv and install all your packages (requirements.txt) in this new virtualenv. Don't yet upgrade Django! Just check if things break and fix them. Then upgrade django in this new virtualenv.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not sure how the project relates to the virtualenv ("clone your project into it"), I can run the same project in multiple different virtualenvs without having to clone it... I'd typically create a new branch when embarking on a big upgrade, that's all.